# What is the best/most important form of publication in applied linguistics/language teaching?

Tags: publications, phd, writing

I'm wondering what it is commonly considered to be of high value/importance amine the types of publications in applied linguistics/language teaching ? Is it journal article, conference paper, book chapter, books...?
What would be the best choice for Phd students seeking a position in Academia ( post-doctoral/assistant professor)

Comment: It is not really easy to answer your question without explicitly telling us what your field is.

Comment: Actually, to be more explicit, this varies drastically by field.

Answer (score 1):

Linguist here.

I would rank publications in the following manner:

1. books (reasonable to make plans while a grad student, but might be too ambitious for most PhD students to actually pursue while they're also working on their dissertations)
2. peer-reviewed journal articles, which I think I'd rank almost alongside books if you're publishing in top-tier journals.
3. book chapters
4. conference proceedings
5. book reviews

If you're only just starting out in your PhD program and haven't tried publishing anything yet, I don't think it's a bad idea to start with conference proceedings (if they come up) or a book review (journals or even through Linguist List), just to get your feet wet. However, as you advance in your PhD program, I would urge you to go up the ladder, and focus on publishing your work as journal articles.

I would also keep in mind that in any given category of publications, there's a lot of variation along the 'prestige' spectrum. For example, a chapter in an edited volume that's being published by university presses like Georgetown or Cambridge would probably be valued more than an article published in a virtually unknown journal.

Comment: At last, a linguist.

Answer (score -3):

The most important publication for you as a PHD student is the publication that will award you your title. Normally that is your doctoral thesis although it can also be paper or two. That depends on your university.

After you get your PHD title then the most valued publications are papers (in peer reviewed journals) because researchers/academics are measured by the number of papers and even required to publish certain amount a year (creating of course a wide net of vicious incentives to publish as much as possible regardless of importance or quality, thats why there are so many predatory journals pout there and a whole business of ghost writing... yeah, I expect the downvotes from this.)

Then the industry (although it depends which) value books (but a book chapter would be a good start and then a book once you have more works to your name) and media content a bit more (Tech for example would value your github stuff and working prototypes/projects more than they care about a paper done during your studies).

So,the answer to what would be best for a PHD student regarding types of publications is to first foucs in whatever publication is useful to finish your PHD according to your school, and secondary about the type of publication that would help you afterwards according to your personal plans to go into the industry or go into academia/research.

NOTE: There's a middle but gray ground regarding research outside of academia and in that case articles might be of consideration for your case.

Comment: Journals aren't the preferred venue in all fields. Hence my comment to the OP.

Comment: I disagree with even the first paragraph of the answer.  Your most important publications as a PhD student are the ones that help you get a job after your PhD.  Just getting the degree is easy in comparison!

Comment: Not to pile on, but I agree with Buffy. Journals are the preferred venues for most of STEM, but parts of CS prefer conferences, and much of the humanities prefers books. Industry is similarly multi-faceted -- though I've never heard of any industry that prefers books, would be interested to learn which industry has that feature. Your advice in the fourth paragraph seems sound, though I imagine OP has deduced that much on their own. Hopefully OP will provide more information.

Comment: @cag51, hmmm. Book publishers prefer books. ;-)  Sorry - a bit orthogonal, I guess.

Comment: @JeffE , First thing is always to get the degree, and for many universities, publishing is requirement for such. Once that is secured, the student can focus on else. Worrying about getting a job afterward its like worrying about what you are going to spend the lottery money before you even buy the lotery ticket.

Comment: @deags No.  *Always* aim past the immediate target.  If you think finishing the PhD is a matter of luck ("a lottery ticket"), either you are woefully underprepared, or your advisor isn't doing their job, or both.

Comment: @JeffE You clearly misunderstood. Getting the title of Doctor is not a matter of luck as you think. It requires a lot of work, 
strenuous amounts of homeworks and projects, and passing through a hell of bureocracy and tramits and permits. For many universities you don't even get to ask a professor to be your advisor until after you finished your PHD, which is when you can start the process of titulation to accredit the title. Please revise the international experience beyond your own opinions.

Comment: @JeffE Luck is an random occurrence. A PHD is the ultimate level of studies in a career and it involves, research, homework and bureocracy. Please revise any dictionary or as a particular question if your confusion remains.

Comment: @deags I've had a PhD for more than two decades; I've graduated several PhD students, some of whom have graduated grand-students.  I've been on dozens of PhD committees, in several different countries. I know exactly what it takes.  I stand by my previous comment.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something in this exchange, but it looks a lot to me like @JeffE is saying "Getting a PhD is not about luck", and deags is saying, "No, you're wrong, getting a PhD is not about luck."

Comment: @Mark Meckes seems about right. Although I cant see where did JeffE got luck involved as something like that is never mentioned.

Comment: @deags: You referred to buying a lottery ticket.

Comment: @ Mark Meckes The whole phrase is 'First thing is always to get the degree, and for many universities, publishing is requirement for such. Once that is secured, the student can focus on else. Worrying about getting a job afterward its like worrying about what you are going to spend the lottery money before you even buy the lottery ticket'